# Android Split string

Tags: java, android, string

I have  a string called `CurrentString` and is in the form of something like this
`"Fruit: they taste good"`.
 I would like to split up the `CurrentString` using the `:` as the delimiter.
So that way the word `"Fruit"` will be split into its own string and `"they taste good"` will be another string.
And then i would simply like to use `SetText()` of 2 different `TextViews` to display that string.

What would be the best way to approach this?

Comment: You could probably try reading into regular expressions. They work fine too.

Comment: @Falmarri - Any unique question about programming is welcome on Stack Overflow.

Answer (score 672, accepted):

```
String currentString = "Fruit: they taste good";
String[] separated = currentString.split(":");
separated[0]; // this will contain "Fruit"
separated[1]; // this will contain " they taste good"
```

You may want to remove the space to the second String:

```
separated[1] = separated[1].trim();
```

If you want to split the string with a special character like dot(.) you should use escape character \ before the dot

Example:

```
String currentString = "Fruit: they taste good.very nice actually";
String[] separated = currentString.split("\\.");
separated[0]; // this will contain "Fruit: they taste good"
separated[1]; // this will contain "very nice actually"
```

There are other ways to do it. For instance, you can use the `StringTokenizer` class (from `java.util`):

```
StringTokenizer tokens = new StringTokenizer(currentString, ":");
String first = tokens.nextToken();// this will contain "Fruit"
String second = tokens.nextToken();// this will contain " they taste good"
// in the case above I assumed the string has always that syntax (foo: bar)
// but you may want to check if there are tokens or not using the hasMoreTokens method
```

Comment: Thanks for this!  Also useful for separating hour and minute when creating a new Time object.

Comment: Thank You! .split() method doesn't works at all in Android! StringTokenizeris working fine.

Comment: Yes it does... what problems did you have?

Comment: split in android receives a regular expression instead of a simple string divider.

Comment: `String.split()` has never existed. Instead, you must call the `.split` method of any instance of `String`. So, if you have something like: `String myString = ...;` then you can do `myString.split(...)`

Comment: How do i parse this kind of string "\/Date(1396448899247+0000)\/", what i wanted is just "1396448899247".

Comment: Without any doubt the  "Split" doesn't work in all Android device!
For some reason doesn't work with my BQ Aquarius and in a Sony Xperia Z1... Thank you!!

Comment: @AyushPateria Android split takes regular expressions so its not the same.

Comment: @Cristian i have String like (123) 123-1234 is my phone number and i want to get only number value for data base inserting. So how to its possible.

Comment: @HardikParmar use regular expressions. There's plenty of information on Google. Good luck.

Comment: @HardikParmar  use `etPhoneNo.getText().toString().replaceAll("\\D", "");` its says that replace all which is not digit

Comment: If you're using `.split()`, pay attention to 2 things: 1 - you're passing a **regular expression** as its parameter, 2 - any **last empty sections will be discarded** unless you pass a 2nd `limit` parameter (with a value of `-1` for the most commonly expected result - see here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14602062/java-string-split-removed-empty-values)

Comment: I was researching the `StringTokenizer` class and came across this... 
[link](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/StringTokenizer.html) 
"StringTokenizer is a legacy class that is retained for compatibility reasons although its use is discouraged in new code. It is recommended that anyone seeking this functionality use the split method of String or the java.util.regex package instead."

Answer (score 88):

.split method will work, but it uses regular expressions.  In this example it would be (to steal from Cristian):

```
String[] separated = CurrentString.split("\\:");
separated[0]; // this will contain "Fruit"
separated[1]; // this will contain " they taste good"
```

Also, this came from:
[Android split not working correctly](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6965642/android-split-not-working-correctly)

Answer (score 56):

android split string by comma

```
String data = "1,Diego Maradona,Footballer,Argentina";
String[] items = data.split(",");
for (String item : items)
{
    System.out.println("item = " + item);
}
```

Answer (score 26):

```
     String s = "having Community Portal|Help Desk|Local Embassy|Reference Desk|Site News";
     StringTokenizer st = new StringTokenizer(s, "|");
        String community = st.nextToken();
        String helpDesk = st.nextToken(); 
        String localEmbassy = st.nextToken();
        String referenceDesk = st.nextToken();
        String siteNews = st.nextToken();
```

Answer (score 22):

You might also want to consider the Android specific [TextUtils.split()](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/text/TextUtils.html#split%28java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String%29) method.

The difference between TextUtils.split() and String.split() is documented with TextUtils.split():

> String.split() returns [''] when the string to be split is empty. This returns []. This does not remove any empty strings from the result.

I find this a more natural behavior. In essence TextUtils.split() is just a thin wrapper for String.split(), dealing specifically with the empty-string case. [The code for the method](http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/ext/com.google.android/android/5.L_preview/android/text/TextUtils.java#TextUtils.split%28java.lang.String%2Cjava.util.regex.Pattern%29) is actually quite simple.

Comment: What's the benefit of using TextUtils.split() instead of just calling split() directly on the string?

Comment: Edited answer to clarify difference between TextUtils.split() and String.split()

Comment: Thanks, I actually read the documentation for TextUtils.split() but for some reason I missed this detail. I guess I was to tired to understand what it actually said.

Answer (score 0):

String s = "String="

String[] str = s.split("=");  //now str[0] is "hello" and str[1] is "goodmorning,2,1"

add this string