# Android split not working correctly

Tags: android, split

I've been developing an Android app for the past 4 Months now and came across the following regarding the split function:

```
String [] arr;
SoapPrimitive result = (SoapPrimitive)envelope.getResponse();
arr = result.toString().trim().split("|");
```

The result variable is what I get after accessing my WebService, now this works perfectly. But, for some reason my split("|") method is not splitting at "|" but rather splitting at every single char in my result String. So my array looks like this:

arr[0] is "H",
arr[1] is "e",
etc......

I don't know why this is happening because I have used it before in the same project and it worked perfectly.

Thank you in advance

Answer (score 72, accepted):

```
arr = result.toString().trim().split("\\|");
```

the param of String.split accept a regular expression.

Comment: Dude! Thank you! I couldn't figure it out! XD

Answer (score 17):

Following code can be used for any pattern splitting.

```
String.split(Pattern.quote("any pattern you would like here !"));
```