# output text line by line

Tags: android, iphone, ios, mobile

I write app for Android such gets data from server in JSON format. Now I get this value in string, but in my application it must look like:

Route:

- 1)first point
- 2)secon point
- 3).....
- n) n point

I read that in Android in textView I can do it if string will be with html tags but I think it is not the best variant. After Android I must do it in iPhone now I don't know how to do that there. Send Routes as Array is not good variant too. Can you say what is the best way to decide this problem?

Comment: Hi, You mean that all your points are in the same String ? like value :"firstpoint,second point , third point" ?

Comment: @user2122876 yes it is so

Answer (score 0):

I couldn't comment b/c of rep, sorry. Could you provide an example of returned JSON string. I think JSON format can be parsed with ease.

If this the case you can parse it in a loop (or another way. I'm not that good at it)

```
String[] parseIt (String JSON){
    String[] list=JSON.split("\\d\\)");
    String[] rlist=new String[list.length-1];
    for(int i=0;i<list.length-1;i++){
        rlist[i]=list[i+1].trim();
    }
    return rlist;
}
```

This might do trick. But you should edit result. I didn't test yet

Edit: I edited code. It simply return the address now with leading whitespace. You can get rid off them using. String trim() method like;

```
list[1].trim();
```

Do it in loop and don't care about first element (index 0).

Edit 2: Now it should work

Comment: 1) Street Lenina 45 2) Street Novomoscowskaa 64 3) Street Lomonosova 34

Comment: in this way it splits by numbers of home too

Comment: As I said, you need to edit entries before done anything. I didn't test it b/c I don'T have a time then. I'll look at it now.

Answer (score 0):

Have a look [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6965642/android-split-not-working-correctly) you will have to find the good [pattern](http://developer.android.com/reference/java/util/regex/Pattern.html) .

Hence you have separated strings just use a list View with an [ArrayAdapter](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/ArrayAdapter.html).

I am not so good with regex but i think it should like : [1-9][0-9]) [[a-f][0-9]]+