# Android: Split a string

Tags: android

Solutions from all other similar threads crashes my app, that's why I had to create this thread.

The string:

```
    FileInputStream fis = null;
    String collected = null;
    try {
        File file = new File(FILENAME);
        if(!file.exists())
        createfileinstantly();
        fis = openFileInput(FILENAME);
        byte[] dataArray = new byte [fis.available()];
        while (fis.read(dataArray) != -1)
           {
           collected = new String(dataArray); 
           } 
       ....
```

Here, "collected" is the string that I want to split. The default value of the string is: "0|0|0|0|0|0|0|0|0"
So I want to use " | " to separate these values.

When I add the following code after the above mentioned code, I get null 9 times:

```
    String[] separated = collected.split("|");
    String splay = separated[0];
    String swin = separated[1];
    String sall = separated[2];
    String sanimal = separated[3];
    String scountry = separated[4];
    String sfruit = separated[5];
    String shuman = separated[6];
    String soccupation = separated[7];
    String smisc = separated[8];
```

To  test the code I'm using a TextView called dataResults:

```
dataResults.setText(splay+swin+sall+sanimal+scountry+sfruit+shuman+soccupation+smisc);
```

I originally wanted to convert these strings to integer (I still want to) so at first I thought there was some problem while converting to integer. But after some testing out it turns that the issue is in splitting the strings. But just to be on the safer side after the main problem could you please add how to convert the split-ed strings to integer.

Thank you very much!

**EDIT:** Even after changing "|" to "\\|" it is still showing "null" 9 times. **Is that different enough?**

Comment: possibly duplicate of the question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10796160/splitting-a-java-string-by-the-pipe-symbol-using-split

Comment: Even after changing "|" to "\\|" it is still showing "null" 9 times. Is that different enough?

Comment: this will work to split a string by '|' . please ensure your string having valid data..

Comment: @Arjun Jadeja    try this...  collected.split("\\|");  but at you case you should get 9 times Null because your string contains null values that is 0.

Comment: The string doesn't contain "null" value. I tried displaying the string in the TextView and I got no problem.

Answer (score 2):

The | character needs to be escaped.

```
String[] separated = collected.split("\\|");
```

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6965642/android-split-not-working-correctly

Comment: As Raghunandan said, it has to be **\\|**. This is because the split() function uses regular expressions.

Comment: Ahhh you're right I forgot for a second that I'm giving the \ to the string and that needs escaping too for Java. Sorry sorry, edited and thanks :)

Comment: Would anybody mind assisting me here?

Comment: Does it properly store the String after it has been read from the byte array? What does System.out.println(collected) print out?

Comment: @Arjun Jadeja    try this...  collected.split("\\|");