# android split string doesn't work correctly

Tags: android

in my android app, i would like to split an array value into another array.

i have an Array with the name ArrayA. 
log of ArrayA[0]:

> Peter|Mustermann

now i would like to split Peter and Mustermann, i try this:

```
String [] ArrayB = ArrayA[0].split("|");
```

But the Log of ArrayB[0] and ArrayB[1] will not be:

> Peter

And

> Mustermann

it will be:

> P

And

> nothing

Any ideas ? :(

Comment: Check out this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6965642/android-split-not-working-correctly?rq=1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just use a single quote

```
String [] ArrayB = ArrayA[0].split('|');
```

Comment: It does not work for me. It splits ArrayA[0] char by char. It does not take '|' as separator.

Answer (score 5):

The `public String[] split(String regex)` works with a regular expression.

In a regular expression `|` is a reserved character, so try to escape it using

`String [] ArrayB = ArrayA[0].split("\\|");`

See here for more information about other reserved characters: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/regex/Pattern.html#sum

And see here for a compilable sample: http://ideone.com/fjXNoJ

Comment: than i get the error: illegal escape character

Comment: thanks Marvin. Updated

Answer (score 1):

You'll have use it as follows:

```
String [] ArrayB  = Array[0].trim().split("\\|");
```

As '\' is a special character also (along with |), two backslashes in a string literal will mean one backslash in the actual String, which in turn will represent a regular expression that matches a single backslash character.