# How to read sms response line by line

Tags: android, sms

This is my code to read sms. I want to read received sms line by line if line one contain no 00 do this if line 2 contain this String  do this etc.

Below is my code which only read smss containing 00 then do this  not read line by line how I       change this code to read sms line by line

```
  public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) 
{
    //---get the SMS message passed in---
    Bundle bundle = intent.getExtras();        
    SmsMessage[] msgs = null;
    String str = "";  

    if (bundle != null)
    {
        //---retrieve the SMS message received---
        Object[] pdus = (Object[]) bundle.get("pdus");
        msgs = new SmsMessage[pdus.length];            
        for (int i=0; i<msgs.length; i++){
            msgs[i] = SmsMessage.createFromPdu((byte[])pdus[i]);                
            str += "SMS from " + msgs[i].getOriginatingAddress();   


            str += " :";
            str += msgs[i].getMessageBody().toString().split("/n");;
            str += "\n"; 






            if(str.contains("00"));
            {


                 Intent l = new Intent(context,AgAppMenu.class);
                 l.putExtra("msg",str);
                 l.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);   
                 context.startActivity(l);


            }
```

Comment: Try using `String.split()` and split by \n

Comment: i cant understand how i use give nay example

Comment: See [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3732790/android-split-string) example or the questions mentioned in the related section of mentioned question.

Answer (score 1):

Use [String.split()](https://developer.android.com/reference/java/lang/String.html#split%28java.lang.String%29).

For example to get the different lines from a String you do:

```
String example = "Hello\nWorld!";
String[] parts = example.split("\n");

// parts[0] contains "Hello"
// parts[1] contains "World!"
```

For your case, to get each line of the message, use something like :

```
String[] msg_lines = msgs[i].getMessageBody().toString().split("/n");
```

So your code may look like:

```
String[] msg_lines = null;
for(...) {
    msgs[i] = SmsMessage.createFromPdu((byte[])pdus[i]);                
    str += "SMS from " + msgs[i].getOriginatingAddress();                     
    str += " :";
    str += msgs[i].getMessageBody().toString();
    str += "\n";

    msg_lines = msgs[i].getMessageBody().toString().split("\n");
    for (String line : msg_lines)
    {
        if (line.contains("00")) { /*then*/ }
    }
}
```

Comment: how do i set in my code i try it like

      str += msgs[i].getMessageBody().toString();
                str += "\n"; 
                
                
                str.split("\n");

                     str[0] contains "Hello"

                if(str.contains("00"));
                {
                 
                  
                  Intent l = new Intent(context,AgAppMenu.class);
                     l.putExtra("msg",str);
                     l.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);   
                     context.startActivity(l);

Comment: You don't even declare str, what is it ? Simply work on `msgs[i].getMessageBody().toString().split("/n");`

Comment: Bundle bundle = intent.getExtras();        
        SmsMessage[] msgs = null;
        String str = "";

Comment: @HayyaANAM "but its show error" -- What error ? I didn't tested my code, but I don't think I messed up too much :)

Comment: i edit my code now see again  how i set this line in my code

parts[0] contains "Hello"
// parts[1] contains "World!"

Comment: Try to take your time and read what you did! This ` str += msgs[i].getMessageBody().toString().split("/n");;` will obviously don't work. And what the use of getting each line if you always test on `str` ?

Comment: Str  store incoming message body and sender number

Comment: geoffory u say me above to do this like 

msgs[i].getMessageBody().toString().split("/n");

Comment: im cofuse  its say do not convert  String str  t0    String [] str

Comment: What are you talking to again? Never said you should convert `str` to `String[]`... What doesn't fit your needs in the code I posted?

Comment: read my code aboove just only tell me how i read  sms in this way 
00
LOG
00
AdeelAslam

Comment: The part after "So your code may look like:" in my answer already told you how to proceed.