# Java String split removed empty values

Tags: java, string, split

I am trying to split the Value using a separator.
But I am finding the surprising results

```
String data = "5|6|7||8|9||";
String[] split = data.split("\\|");
System.out.println(split.length);
```

I am expecting to get 8 values. **[5,6,7,EMPTY,8,9,EMPTY,EMPTY]**
But I am getting only 6 values.

Any idea and how to fix. No matter EMPTY value comes at anyplace, it should be in array.

Answer (score 649, accepted):

`split(delimiter)` by default removes trailing empty strings from result array. To turn this mechanism off we need to use overloaded version of `split(delimiter, limit)` with `limit` set to negative value like

```
String[] split = data.split("\\|", -1);
```

Little more details:
`split(regex)` internally returns result of `split(regex, 0)` and in [documentation](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#split-java.lang.String-int-) of this method you can find (emphasis mine)

> The `limit` parameter controls the number of times the pattern is applied and therefore affects the length of the resulting array.
>
> If the limit `n` is *greater than zero* then the pattern will be applied at most n - 1 times, the array's length will be no greater than n, and the array's last entry will contain all input beyond the last matched delimiter.
>
> If `n` is **non-positive** then the pattern will be applied as many times as possible and the array can have any length.
>
> If `n` is **zero** then the pattern will be applied as many times as possible, the array can have any length, and **trailing empty strings will be discarded**.

**Exception**:

It is worth mentioning that removing trailing empty string makes sense *only if such empty strings were created by the split mechanism*. So for `"".split(anything)` since we can't split `""` farther we will get as result `[""]` array.
It happens because split didn't happen here, so `""` despite being empty and trailing represents *original* string, not empty string which was *created* by splitting process.

Comment: wow. that worked brilliantly. but -1 how this changes everything?

Comment: you can even try with `data.split("\\|", 8)`

Comment: **Don't use `split("\\|", 8)` because this limits to the first eight tokens!** If your string is variable, you should use `split("\\|", -1)` so that it creates an unlimited number of tokens and **doesn't** discard empty tokens at the end.

Comment: @Reddy -1 (_or any negative number in fact, it doesn't matter what the absolute value is_) tells the split method to keep the empty tokens at the end. The default is 0, which tells the method to discard empty tokens at the end of the array.

Comment: You could also change the regex to search for 'one-or-more' occurrences: `data.split("\\|+")`

Comment: I edited your answer trying to include more explanation (I used my [previous answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/29972465/1393766) as base). Hope you don't mind.

Comment: Apparently, a lot of people expected that keeping the trailing empty strings is the default functionality for `split(regex)`. They ended up here and found out that it isn't.

Comment: Why does a String containing empty space character as last character gets returned 
when delimitter is an empty space character " " ?
  
Eg: `String s = "a ";
public static int lengthOfLastWord(String s) {
    int l = 0;
    for(String eachWord : s.split("\\s+", -1)){
        if(!eachWord.equals(" ")){
            l = eachWord.length();
            System.out.println("'" + eachWord + "'");                
        }
    } 
    return l;
}`

returns 'a' and ' '.

Whereas, if `String s = "a a";`
then output is just 'a' followed by another 'a'

Why is this happening in Java 8?

Answer (score 40):

From the documentation of [`String.split(String regex)`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#split%28java.lang.String%29):

> This method works as if by invoking the two-argument split method with the given expression and a limit argument of zero. **Trailing empty strings are therefore not included in the resulting array.**

So you will have to use the two argument version [`String.split(String regex, int limit)`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#split%28java.lang.String,%20int%29) with a negative value:

```
String[] split = data.split("\\|",-1);
```

Doc:

> If the limit n is greater than zero then the pattern will be applied at most n - 1 times, the array's length will be no greater than n, and the array's last entry will contain all input beyond the last matched delimiter. **If n is non-positive then the pattern will be applied as many times as possible and the array can have any length. If n is zero then the pattern will be applied as many times as possible, the array can have any length, and trailing empty strings will be discarded.**

This will not leave out any empty elements, including the trailing ones.

Answer (score 7):

`String[] split = data.split("\\|",-1);`

This is not the actual requirement in all the time. The Drawback of above is show below:

```
Scenerio 1:
When all data are present:
    String data = "5|6|7||8|9|10|";
    String[] split = data.split("\\|");
    String[] splt = data.split("\\|",-1);
    System.out.println(split.length); //output: 7
    System.out.println(splt.length); //output: 8
```

When data is missing:

```
Scenerio 2: Data Missing
    String data = "5|6|7||8|||";
    String[] split = data.split("\\|");
    String[] splt = data.split("\\|",-1);
    System.out.println(split.length); //output: 5
    System.out.println(splt.length); //output: 8
```

Real requirement is length should be 7 although there is data missing. Because there are cases such as when I need to insert in database or something else. We can achieve this by using below approach.

```
    String data = "5|6|7||8|||";
    String[] split = data.split("\\|");
    String[] splt = data.replaceAll("\\|$","").split("\\|",-1);
    System.out.println(split.length); //output: 5
    System.out.println(splt.length); //output:7
```

What I've done here is, I'm removing "|" pipe  at the end and then splitting the  String. If you have "," as a seperator then you need to add ",$" inside replaceAll.

Answer (score 5):

From [**String.split() API Doc**](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#split%28java.lang.String%29):

> Splits this string around matches of the given regular expression.
>   This method works as if by invoking the two-argument split method with
>   the given expression and a limit argument of zero. Trailing empty
>   strings are therefore not included in the resulting array.

Overloaded [**String.split(regex, int)**](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#split%28java.lang.String,%20int%29) is more appropriate for your case.

Comment: That explains the behaviour but does not answer the question.

Comment: @assylias added it to my answer now :)

Answer (score 3):

you may have multiple separators, including whitespace characters, commas, semicolons, etc. take those in repeatable group with []+, like:

```
 String[] tokens = "a , b,  ,c; ;d,      ".split( "[,; \t\n\r]+" );
```

you'll have 4 tokens -- a, b, c, d

leading separators in the source string need to be removed before applying this split.

as answer to question asked:

```
String data = "5|6|7||8|9||";
String[] split = data.split("[\\| \t\n\r]+");
```

whitespaces added just in case if you'll have those as separators along with |