# String split function in Java

Tags: java, android, string

I have a `String` and I want to split it by **","**

If suppose I have a String like,

```
 String test = "aa,bb,cc";
```

now I can split it by,

```
String[] spl = test.split(",");
```

And the **spl.length** is **3**

If suppose my String is

```
 String test = ",,,";
```

Here the splitted String **length** is **0**. But my expected answer is **3**. 
My test `String` is dynamaic value and it may varies like, Now think I have a String like

`String test = ",aa,dd,,,,,ff,gg"`

Now the splited array length is **4**. But I expected answer is **9**
And I need to split by **","** and I need the **aa** position at **spl[1]** and **dd** position as **spl[2]** and **ff** position as **spl[7]**

Can someone give the suggestion about to solve this issue..

Comment: Just try with the overloaded `split(",",-1)` and see.

Comment: Have a look at this post: http://stackoverflow.com/a/14602089/3579095

Comment: @TheNewIdiot it wont give the answer as 3 it gives 4 :(

Comment: @Lars - gives 4 and not 3. `String[] spl = test.split("\\,", -1);`

Comment: @No_Rulz Then please let us know on what basis did you determine that the second split should give 4 and the third split 9.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Use split() with -1 as limit

```
     public static void main(String[] args) {
    String test = ",,,";
    System.out.println(Arrays.toString(test.split(",", -1))); // adds leading and trailing empty Strings .
    // so effectively its like adding "" before , after and between each ","

    String test1 = "aa,bb,cc";
    System.out.println(Arrays.toString(test1.split(",",-1)));
}
```

O/P :

```
[, , , ] -- > Length =4
[aa, bb, cc]
```

Comment: `,,,` gives me 4 and not 3.

Comment: public static void main(String[] args) {
  String test = ",,,"; 
  String[] spl = test.split(",", -1);
  System.out.println(spl.length);

}

Comment: @TheLostMind the answer is 4 not 3

Comment: @No_Rulz When you perform a split operation on a subject containing the delimiter 3 times, the output will be 4 elements, not 3 elements. Your expected result for `",,,".split(",", -1);` should be 4. Look at your example for: `"aa,bb,cc"`, the delimiter only occurs twice and you expect 3 elements to be returned, why would you not expect 4 elements to return when you have the delimiter 3 times?

Comment: @DanTemple yes I agree with you :)

Comment: @all -My bad.. This does return 4(forgot that a trailing empty string will also be added when we split.).. - edited my answer.

Comment: @TheLostMind after reading dantemple comment only I also recognize my mistake.. and thanks for your answer :)

Comment: @TheLostMind Ok, but your answer is still right :) As Dan Temple said, when you have a string like `a,b,c` you have two commas, but after splitting the resulting array will hold three values. So, the OP should expect that `,,,` will be splitted to four values, not three, that would be wrong.

Answer (score 2):

To get the behavior you want you can just replace "," by " ,":

```
String test = ",,";
test = test.replace(",", " ,");
System.out.println((test.split(",").length));
```

Comment: Is this extra step of modifying a string really needed ?

Comment: Misread the answer, sorry. Anyway, TheLostMind's answer is the correct one. No need to replace, the `split` method just does the job

Comment: @PabloFranciscoPérezHidalgo - it needs to be changed. See the comments there.

Comment: @james I did not see the comments, yes. It is true. If I were coding the OP program I would use replace as I answered.

Comment: @james Do u have any suggestion about my question?

Comment: @No_Rulz - sorry, can't think of a solution.

Comment: @No_Rulz Isn't ok for you the replace solution?

Comment: @PabloFranciscoPérezHidalgo yes dude, it must solve my issue.. If suppose I have 50 "," means I need to use replace() and other hand side I need to use trim() function also.. It has some extra steps.. Now I used like your answer. But I look better answer dude..

Answer (score 0):

With the `split()` function, java separates a String by the Substring of your choice. If there is nothing between them, the field will not be `null`, it will just be skipped.

In other programming languages, you could come across something like this:

```
String example = ',,,'
String[] example2 = example.split(',')
print(example2.length())
```

This could also deliver 4. Because there are 4 spaces around the `','` chars:

`1,2,3,4`