# Scala regex match and split

Tags: regex, scala

So here's what I want to do:

input string: `"abc From: blah"`
I want to split this so that the result is

```
["abc" "From: blah"] or ["abc" "From" "blah"
```

I have several other patterns to match
    `["abcd" "To:" "blah"]` etc

So I have the following regex

```
val datePattern = """((.*>.*)|(.*(On).*(wrote:)$)|(.*(Date):.*(\+\d\d\d\d)?$)|(.*(From):.*(\.com)?(\]|>)?$))"""
val reg = datePattern.r
```

If I do a match the result comes out fine.
If I do a split on the same regex I get an empty list.

```
inputStr match {
      case reg(_*) => return "Match"
      case _ => return "Output: None"
}
```

on the input string :

```
"abc From: blah blah"
```

returns Match

Split

```
inputStr.split(datePattern)
```

returns an empty array. What am I possibly missing ?

Comment: You cannot have one and the same regex to match and to split a string, unless you expect to get different results.

Comment: Sorry didn't quite get that. So the split regex has to be different ? I tried just doing the split without the match - even then the split failed. Scala noob here.

Comment: I think you can do that with [`"abc From: blah".split("\\W+")`](http://ideone.com/LpzvGm).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since the regexp matches the string, split will remove the entire string (considered as a separator).
The default behavior is not to return two empty strings, but an empty array in this case, as given by the split signification.

https://stackoverflow.com/a/14602089/1287856

Concerning why your regex matches in its entirety, you might find this website useful (it concerns your example directly)

https://regex101.com/r/zY0lX9/1

Split finds the **whole** regexp and removes all its occurences from the string, returning the interleaved strings as an array. You may want to split on something like `"(?=From:)"` so that it does not remove anything.

Comment: Thank you. That was very helpful. I'm still a bit stumped as to why "abc From: def" is matched in it's entirety. I'm expecting on the 'From:' substring to match as evidenced by the regex. So shouldn't I get "abc" "From: def" or something like that upon splitting ?