# How do I get the same results with Java split as with Python split

Tags: java, python, regex

In Java:

```
String base = "a|a||";
String[] stri= .split("\\|");
```

produces a string array with length 2.

On the other hand in python:

```
base = "a|a||"
base.split("|")
```

produces an array with length 4.
What do I have to do to get the same result in Java?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14602062/java-string-split-removed-empty-values

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use split with limit set to negative value:

```
String base = "a|a||";
String[] stri= .split("\\|", -1);
```

From the [docs](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#split(java.lang.String,%20int)) (the number at the and is `n`):

> If n is non-positive then the pattern will be applied as many times as possible and the array can have any length.