# Insert whitespace between two characters in a string if a condition is met

Tags: java, string, split

I have a string in the following format:

```
"0,0,0,0|1,0,0,0,0|1,1,0,1"
```

but there can be numbers missing, like this:

```
"0,0,,|1,,,1,0|,1,1,1"
```

I want to extract the data from each of those blocks between the '|' character. Getting to the individual blocks is fairly easy:

```
"0,0,,|1,,,1,0|,1,1,1".split("|");
```

now when I try to split the blocks, I lose information:

```
"0,0,,".split(",");
```

becomes an array of two elements `["0","0"]`

```
",1,1,1".split(",");
```

becomes `["","1","1","1"]`, exactly what I want. An array of four elements, one of which is an empty string

How can I split the array, without losing information, i.e. the resulting array being one of length 4 in the case of `"0,0,,".split(",")`? An idea of mine is in the title, but I don't know how to implement it

EDIT: I tried doing this before splitting by `","`

```
someVar= "0,0,,".replaceAll(",,", ", ,");
```

which works fine between two commas (as expected), but it doesn't work for the last missing value:

splitting someVar will give us `["0","0"," "]`

Comment: if the there is no number do you assume it to be zero, so for your example you want 0,0,, to become 0,0,0,0?

Comment: Or you want to become `"0", "0", " "`?

Comment: you want your array to become like this `["0","0",""]` ?

Comment: Since there are 3 commas I think he wants `["0","0","",""]`

Comment: Duplicate of: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14602062/java-string-split-removed-empty-values

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Java String split removed empty values](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14602062/java-string-split-removed-empty-values)

Comment: @JorgeCampos I had not found the post you linked. It might really be a duplicate. I'll try out the solution there

Comment: Have you read the question I marked yours as a duplicate? No need for a replace. Just use the second parameter of split method. As the docs mentions it.

Comment: @JorgeCampos It worked, thanks for finding the other post!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

String[] result = text.split("\|", any negative value);

Use this. This will fix your issue.