# Java Split Method Returns Empty Token

Tags: java

My source string is `/study[2]/`

When I do

```
String[] tokens = itemPath.split("/");
```

the result is

```
[, study[2]]
```

tokens is String[2]

I was under the impression that the Split method removed all empty tokens? Why is it keeping the 1st one? I shouldn't get this according to [Java String split removed empty values](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14602062/java-string-split-removed-empty-values)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The first sentence of the accepted answer to the question you linked:

> `split(delimiter)` by default removes **trailing** empty strings from result array.

*(my emphasis)*

Yours isn't trailing (at the end), it's *leading* (at the beginning). `split` doesn't remove those. It also doesn't remove ones in the middle.