# Handle Missing values in file using scala

Tags: scala

I have read file using scala and for the missing values I have to print as "Missing". I have used `case`/`match`/`Some`/`Option` to handle it. I end up with `IndexOutOfBound` exception. I have used try catch as well in the code but no luck. Any help will be appreciated ??

I am reading a file and the file has some missing values I have to update it with value as "MISSING".

```
    package HW9

    object WeatherStub {
      //Assigning file name        
      val fileName = "weather.csv"

      def main(args: Array[String]): Unit = {
        //Calling the read Weather method
        readWeather(fileName)

      }

    //Method to handle missing and exception
      def readWeather(fn: String): Unit = {
        var weatherMuteMap = scala.collection.mutable.Map[String, String]()
        def IsEmptyOrNull(s:String): Option[String] =   {try {Some(s.toString)} catch {case _ => None}}

    //Reading files
        for(line <- io.Source.fromFile(fn).getLines()){
          val list1 = line.split(",").map(_.trim).toList

    //Handling missing values
          val TotalPrecp = IsEmptyOrNull(list1(1).toString) match { case Some(i) => i case _ => "Missing"}
          val LowPrecp = IsEmptyOrNull(list1(2).toString) match { case Some(i) => i   case _ => "Missing" }
          val HighPrecp = IsEmptyOrNull(list1(3).toString) match { case Some(i) => i   case _ => "Missing" }

//Concatenating values to a map
          weatherMuteMap(list1(0)) = TotalPrecp + LowPrecp + HighPrecp
//Print    
          println(weatherMuteMap)

        }
      }

      }
```

Sample Data from file:-

```
    2016-01-01,0,-13.28,-1.11
    2016-01-02,0,-10,0
    2016-01-03,0,-10,0
    2016-01-04,0,-12.78,-2.22
    2016-01-06,0,-6.11,0.61
    2016-01-07,0.05,-0.61,1
    2016-01-08,0.1,,1
    2016-01-09,0.13,-5.61,0
    2016-01-21,0,,
    2016-01-22,0,,
    2016-01-23,,-9.39,-6.11
    2016-02-19,0,,
    2016-02-20,0,0,0
    2016-02-21,,,
    2016-02-22,0,-0.61,0.61
    2016-02-23,,,

    Error:-

    Exception in thread "main" java.lang.IndexOutOfBoundsException: 2
        at scala.collection.LinearSeqOptimized$class.apply(LinearSeqOptimized.scala:65)
        at scala.collection.immutable.List.apply(List.scala:84)
        at HW9.WeatherStub$$anonfun$readWeather$1.apply(WeatherStub.scala:19)
        at HW9.WeatherStub$$anonfun$readWeather$1.apply(WeatherStub.scala:16)
        at scala.collection.Iterator$class.foreach(Iterator.scala:893)
        at scala.collection.AbstractIterator.foreach(Iterator.scala:1336)
        at HW9.WeatherStub$.readWeather(WeatherStub.scala:16)
        at HW9.WeatherStub$.main(WeatherStub.scala:8)
        at HW9.WeatherStub.main(WeatherStub.scala)

    Process finished with exit code 1
```

Comment: can you format your question properly?

Answer (score 1):

If you run some of the examples of your data:

```
scala> val str = "2016-02-23,,,"
scala> str.split(",").map(_.trim).toList
res0: List[String] = List(2016-02-23)
```

You can see that you are only getting the first value in the list, hence the IndexOutOfBoundsException error. You can turn off this behaviour like this:

```
scala> str.split(",", -1).map(_.trim).toList
res1: List[String] = List(2016-02-23, "", "", "")
```

Have a look at this thread that explains why: [Java String split removed empty values](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14602062/java-string-split-removed-empty-values)

EDIT:

There are two things in your code that don't make sense, the definition of `IsEmptyOrNull` takes a `String` so that would never fail in the `try` block, therefore it'd never return None. Also `line.split` would always return an `Array[String]`, so the elements are already `String`. You could think, how empty and missing values are represented in the data, and replace `IsEmptyOrNull` with something like this:

```
def IsEmptyOrNull(s: String): Option[String] = {
  s match {
    case "" => None
    case _ => Some(s)
  }
}
```

Comment: That is a good catch. Thanks!!. I am able to fix that inbound error exception but still the value "Missing" is not being printed at all. Not sure why??