# Last lines not being split if they are blank when splitting String by lines in Java

Tags: java, gwt, split

I'm trying to split `String` by lines. The problem is I'm unable to split last lines if they're empty.

For example if input `String` is like this:

```
asd\n\na\n\n\n
```

I use split like this:

```
Split(String input) {

    List<String> list = new ArrayList<String>(Arrays.asList(input.split("\n")));
    GWT.log("How many lines: "+list.size());

}
```

I get `How many lines: 3` on the logs, although it has to be 5. Last two blank lines is not being split. What am I missing?

Comment: Actually, your answer is here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14602062/java-string-split-removed-empty-values (which is very cool, because I did not know that.)

Comment: @MikeNakis Thanks, `input.split("\n", -1)` worked!