# How to include trailing empty strings in Pattern.compile("\\R").splitAsStream(input)?

Tags: java, regex, newline

This is not a duplication of [Java String split removed empty values](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14602089/1140754), which deals with `split()` method returning a new array. In this case I would like to **avoid the array**.

I solved this problem with a workaround, which I am posting below as a possible solution to my question.

My goal is to process all lines including empty strings such as the following example:

```
String input = "foo\nbar\n\n\nzul\n\n\n";
Pattern NEWLINE = Pattern.compile("\\R");
int [] count = {1};
NEWLINE
    .splitAsStream(input)
    .forEach(line -> System.out.println(count[0]++ + ": " + line));
```

which produces:

```
1: foo
2: baz
3: 
4: 
5: zul
```

Yet, it is missing:

```
6: 
7:
```

**How to include last empty lines?**

Answer (score 2):

You can use [a lookahead](https://www.regular-expressions.info/lookaround.html) `(?=(\\R))` to ensure that the `\\R` delimiter is not consumed and then remove it yourself with `String.trim()`.

```
String input = "foo\nbar\n\n\nzul\n\n\n";
Pattern NEWLINE = Pattern.compile("(?=(\\R))");
int[] count = {1};
NEWLINE.splitAsStream(input)
       .map(String::trim)
       .forEach(line -> System.out.println(count[0]++ + ": " + line));
```

It will however result in a zero-length match for `""` after the last `\n`.

```
1: foo
2: bar
3: 
4: 
5: zul
6: 
7: 
8:
```

Comment: There is an extra line (i.e. 8) which I would like to avoid. Maybe using a `reduce` rather than `forEach`, like `reduce((prev, next) --> .../* use prev */ )` solves it. Is it reasonable?

Comment: Your "extra" line 8 is the same as lines 6 and 7, and zero-length match. There is nothing special about line 8 and there is no way to remove it quickly with a `Pattern` as far as I know. You could do `split(regex, 7)` if you know there are `7` entries.

Comment: Yes, but with the `reduce((prev, next) --> ...` and ignoring `next` we will avoid the last one.

Comment: `String.split(pattern, -1)` creates a new array which I mentioned in OP that I would like to avoid, so I would not include that option in your answer.

Answer (score 1):

As an alternative you can make your own implementation of an equivalent method to `splitAsStream()`, which includes trailing empty strings and still **avoids the instantiation of an array**, such as:

```
static Stream<String> splitAsStream(Pattern p, CharSequence input) {
    Spliterator<String> iter = new Spliterators.AbstractSpliterator<String>(
        Long.MAX_VALUE,
        Spliterator.ORDERED | Spliterator.SIZED
    ) {
        int index = 0;
        final Matcher m = p.matcher(input);

        @Override
        public boolean tryAdvance(Consumer<? super String> action) {
            while(m.find()) {
                if (index != 0 || index != m.start() || m.start() != m.end()) {
                    action.accept(input.subSequence(index, m.start()).toString());
                    index = m.end();
                    return true;
                }
            }
            if(index < input.length()) {
                // Add remaining segment
                action.accept(input.subSequence(index, input.length()).toString());
                index = input.length();
                return true;
            } else {
                return false;
            }
        }
    };
    return StreamSupport.stream(iter, false);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Since [java 9 on can use Matcher.results() yielding a `Stream<MatchResult>`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/util/regex/Matcher.html#results())

```
Pattern.compile("(.*)\\R").matcher(input)
    .results(mr -> System.out.println(count[0]++ + ": " + mr.group(1)));
```

This guarantees that the final "line" has a terminating `\n` too.
"....\nabc" will discard the last abc though.

For that I think the following should work (note `group()`), using a lookahead and requiring for the end `$` at least one char `.`.

```
Pattern.compile(".*(?=\\R)|.$)").matcher(input)
    .results(mr -> System.out.println(count[0]++ + ": " + mr.group()));
```

A split with -1 and a check on the last entry seems a bit more readable.

Comment: Your first approach is correct if you replace `results(...)` by `results().forEach(...)`. The method `results()` is parameter-less