# how to split the csv line in java when the last value is empty

Tags: java, arrays, string

I have comma separated values like below

```
String s1 = "a, b, c, d, e";
String s2 = "a, , , d, ";
String s3 = "a, b, c, d, ";
```

I need to split this string with ",". But the number of values should be 5. I mean the last empty value should present in the output array.
Is there any solution for this.

Comment: you could use the `split` method from `String`

Comment: *the last empty value should present in the output array* it will be present. As long as there are 4 commas at each line, split() will create an array of 5 items.

Comment: @forpas `System.out.println("2,3,4,5,".split(",").length);` returns 4. From the docs for `split(String regex)`: *Trailing empty strings are therefore not included in the resulting array.*

Comment: @GBlodgett The OP's strings all contain a space after the comma. This is why he will get 5 items.

Comment: You actually can't use regex to parse CSV.  It requires a parser.  I suggest the Apache Commons one: https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-csv/

Answer (score 1):

I used String.split(String regex) method and see the Array has 5 elements. I hope this answers your query.

```
package net.javapedia.StringSplitExample;

public class Main {

    public static void main (String[] s) {

        String s1 = "a, b, c, d, e";
        String s2 = "a, , , d, ";
        String s3 = "a, b, c, d, ";
        // This is the String that issue is reported
        String s4 = "a,b,c,d,";
        String s5 = "a,b,c,d,";

        String[] s1Array= s1.split(",");
        String[] s2Array= s2.split(",");
        String[] s3Array= s3.split(",");
        //Below split ignore empty string
        String[] s4Array= s4.split(",");
        //Below split doesn't
        String[] s5Array= s5.split(",",-1);

        System.out.println(s1Array.length);
        System.out.println(s2Array.length);
        System.out.println(s3Array.length);
        //Prints 4
        System.out.println(s4Array.length);
        //Prints 5 :)
        System.out.println(s5Array.length);
    }

}
```

**Output:**

[image]

[Reference](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14602062/java-string-split-removed-empty-values)

Comment: Thanks for pointing it out. After fixing that I am able to see 4 chars. I did some analysis and found a good reference in stack overflow itself. Updating the answer with the same. Hope this helps. Kindly let me know if it doesn't. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You could just use the split method :

`String[] S2 = s2.split(",");`

To prove it works ->

```
System.out.println(S2.length);
for (String str : S2) {
     if (str.equals(" ")) {
         System.out.println("Space");
     } else {
         System.out.println(str);
}
```

Comment: not sure why someone would downvote this answer. It answers the OP's specific posted question and also provides valid proof. Its a different thing if the OP didn't have an empty space as the last string. But that's not true in this case.