# Working of split method for 0.0.0.0. && 0.0.0.0

Tags: java, string

`

```
class GfG{
public String multiply(String a,String b){
        String s = "0.0.0.0";
        String[] str = s.split("\\.");
        for(String p:str){
            System.out.println(p);
        }
        return "";
    }
}
```

`
I am splitting "0.0.0.0" and "0.0.0.0.".
In both the cases i m getting same array of strings i.e 4 "0" strings.
Can someone explain how this split is working for the two above cases.

Comment: What code have you written ?

Comment: i added the code for "0.0.0.0"

Comment: Try String[] str = s.split("\\.", -1); and see the magic.

Answer (score 2):

The reason that you are not receiving the empty string that you think *should* have been returned at the end is by design in `split`.

From the docs:

```
public String[] split(String regex)
```

> This method works as if by invoking the two-argument split method with
>   the given expression and a limit argument of zero. Trailing empty
>   strings are therefore not included in the resulting array

The important part of this is that *Trailing empty string are therefore not included*.

Reference: [Official documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#split(java.lang.String))

Answer (score 1):

It appears that you ran the following

```
jshell> "0.0.0.0".split("\\.")
$1 ==> String[4] { "0", "0", "0", "0" }

jshell> "0.0.0.0.".split("\\.")
$2 ==> String[4] { "0", "0", "0", "0" }
```

and you are happy with the first result but you are wondering why the last result is not

```
String[4] { "0", "0", "0", "0", "" }
```

This is a good question to ask because if the dot was at the beginning of the string you would get the empty string!

```
jshell> ".0.0.0.0".split("\\.")
$3 ==> String[5] { "", "0", "0", "0", "0" }
```

This is just how `split` works. If there is a delimiter at the end of the string, no empty string is returned.

Duplicate of [Java String split removed empty values](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14602062/java-string-split-removed-empty-values), where it is explained in detail.