# Java Spark - Issue in filtering records in RDD based on number of columns

Tags: java, apache-spark, rdd

This is a different issue, i am trying to filter the records in RDD based on the number of columns. This is more like a File processing.

I have written the same in Pyspark and i see the records are filtering properly. 
When i am trying in Java the Valid Records are going to Error Folder.

Downloaded the Error Files and validated using AWK to find they are having 996 column, but still getting filtered out in the Error.

In python the exact number of Files filtered are error files.

Below is the piece of Snippet.

---

```
JavaRDD<String> inputDataRDD = sc.textFile(args[0]+"/"+args[1], 5000);

int columnLength = Integer.parseInt(args[3]);

inputDataRDD
.filter(filterData -> filterData.split("\t").length == columnLength)
.coalesce(1)
.saveAsTextFile(args[2]+"Valid/", GzipCodec.class);

inputDataRDD
.filter(filterData -> filterData.split("\t").length != columnLength)
.coalesce(1)
.saveAsTextFile(args[2]+"Error/", GzipCodec.class);
```

---

End of Snippet..

There are close to 10M records in that file.

Is there any difference in the sc.textfile (filename , int numPartitions) between Java and Python or am i missing anything.

Need your assistance to find out the mistake i have made.

Note :-Did a maven build using eclipse and ran the following command in Yarn.

```
spark-submit --class com.virtualpairprogrammers.ProcessFilesToHDFS --master yarn learningSpark-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar "/input/ABFeeds/" "ABFeeds_2020-04-20.tsv.gz" "/output/ABFeeds/2020-05-06/" 996
```

Thanks in Advance

Regards

Sam

Comment: When valid records are being sent to Error folder, did you check what is the column count that your Spark Java program is calculating ?

Comment: @kaysush - The Column count passed is a constant number for both Valid and Error. It is not changing anytime in between.

Comment: Sorry, I wasn't articulate enough. I wished to know what is `filterData.split("\t").length` expression returning for Valid rows ?

Comment: @kaysush : I tried to print the following using the following statement , but it is not printing when running.

inputDataRDD.foreach(value -> System.out.println(value.split("\t").length));

Comment: @kaysush :  I think i got why it is not printing. Fixed it for my sample data. Let me run it for my valid data to see what is the output.

Comment: @kaysush :  I am printing the length for Valid and Error records. 
For Valid Records i see 996 columns are there. For the Error records i see 995 as length. 
When using the AWK command from Unix to print for Valid and Error i am seeing length as 996 only.

Comment: I am able to see the issue. When running from Java , i see that sc.textfile() is not considering the last tab.
Taken a single Line, from error and identified that the Unix is considering the last column and printing a space, but when printed from Java it does not print the last line as blank.

Any suggestions to the same ? or anyone has faced that issue earlier.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue is with the Split command which i was using.
Issue :- When the last column in empty , Java split is not able to consider it as a column. 
I had referred the following site, which talks about the Split issue

[Java String split removed empty values](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14602062/java-string-split-removed-empty-values)

Old Snippet :

```
inputDataRDD
    .filter(filterData -> filterData.split("\t").length == columnLength)
    .coalesce(1)
    .saveAsTextFile(args[2]+"Valid/", GzipCodec.class);
```

Modified Snippet :

```
inputDataRDD
    .filter(filterData -> filterData.split("\t",-1).length == columnLength)
    .coalesce(1)
    .saveAsTextFile(args[2]+"Valid/", GzipCodec.class);
```

I have tested it and it is working.

Thanks all for the assistance.

Regards