# How to split a text into 2 different sentences and then count the words of each sentence in Java

Tags: java

Example I have this sentence "Hello, my name is Pedro. I want to go to Paris. I'm going to buy the ticket"

I want to separate the text into several sentences where the point appears and then tell which sentence has more words

I came up with this to count the words but I don't know how to separate it into different sentences to count it

```
public static int countWordsUsingSplit(String parrafo) {

         if (parrafo == null || parrafo.isEmpty()) {
             return 0;
         }
         String[] words = parrafo.split("\\.?!");
         return words.length;

     }
```

Comment: Is the missing period after "ticket" deliberate or a typo?  Split by ".", trim, then split by space.

Comment: So if the last sentence doesn't have a `.` as in your example then does that mean we don't consider it as a sentence. Can you give sample input / output?

Answer (score 0):

```
int maxWords = 0;
String maxString;
String[] sentences = new String[parrafo.count(".")];
sentences = parrafo.split(". ");

for(int i = 0; i <= sentences.size(); i++){ //Might as well be .length(), I'm not sure
if(sentences[i].count(" ") + 1 > maxWords){
maxWords = sentences[i].count(" ") + 1;
maxString = sentences[i];
}}
System.out.println(maxString);
```

Answer (score 0):

You are on the right track. [String.split](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/lang/String.html#split(java.lang.String)) takes a [regular expression](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Regular_expression) ([Java details)](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/util/regex/Pattern.html#sum) not literal characters. A dot in a regular expression means "any character", so your split will lots of empty strings, which `split` supresses, and you get no output.

You need to escape the dot so that it loses its special meaning and you can match on  literal dots. You do that by putting a backslash in front of it. But because backslashes are escape characters themselves in Java Strings, you need to escape the backslash with another backslash: `"\\."`.

Then you split each sentence at white space (`\s` in regex lingo) and count the words. Add a `+` after the `\s` to indicate you want one or more spaces, or use `*` instead of the `+` for zero to many (any number).

Here is a complete example:

```java
public class LongestSentenceOfMany {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        String input = "Hello, my name is Pedro. I want to go to Paris. I'm going to buy the ticket";
 
        // String[] sentences = input.split("\\.");
        String[] sentences = input.split("\\s*\\.\\s*");

        String longestSentence = null;
        int longestCount = -1;
        for (String sentence : sentences) {
            String[] words = sentence.split("\\s+");
            System.out.println("\"" + sentence + "\" has " + words.length + " words.");
            if (longestSentence == null || words.length < longestCount) {
                longestSentence = sentence;
            }
        }
 
        if (longestSentence != null) {
            System.out.println("\"" + longestSentence + "\" is the longest sentence");
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can just use the stream api and some regex magic:

```java
String msg = "Hello, my name is Pedro. I want to go to Paris? I'm going to buy the ticket! ";

Optional<String> result = Arrays.stream(msg.split("(\\. )|(! )|(\\? )"))
        .max((sentence1, sentence2) -> sentence1.length() < sentence2.length() ? -1 : 1);
```

I am not that good with regex, which means this can likely be improved. This method will not count the ". ", "! ", "? " characters. You can customize the regex to fit your needs. If you wanted to have the smallest sentence just replace the "<" with ">". [Here](https://regexr.com/) is an amazing site for creating regex.

Answer (score -2):

Hey you can use split as

```
String[] words = parrafo.split(".");
```

to only get the sentences seperate by point but you can use your's either to seperate with ? and !.

After that you should look out all the strings that you had in words. To do that you need a loop to travel all. You can use

```
String maxString=words[0];
int maxLength=words[0].length;

for(String str: words){
   if(str.length > maxLength){
      maxLength=str.length;
      maxString = str;
   }
}

return maxString
```

We define two variable to keep biggest length of strings for compare and get the string if bigger than maxLength

Hope works

Comment: `.split(".")` does _not_ separate the string into sentences. Nor does their `"\\.?!"` split it by questions marks and exclamation marks.

Comment: Please, enlighten us @Ivar

Comment: The `.split()` method takes a regular expression as an argument. The dot (`.`) in a regular expression [matches (almost) any character](https://www.regular-expressions.info/dot.html). So `parrafo.split(".")` will split on _every_ character, not literal dots. You will get an array of empty results (the characters between every character). (But due to how `.split()` works, [it will remove empty tailing strings](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14602062/java-string-split-removed-empty-values), so the result will be an empty array in this case.) I'd recommend testing your solutions.