# How to split this string using split function()

Tags: java, android

I hava one string   "2013-1-31  08:25 PM"

i want to split from space and :

i able to split after space it become  "2013-1-31  08"  and "25 PM"

now i want the "2013-1-31"  and "08"

i dont not able to get the value in the 08 in the new string but i get the "2013-1-31"

```
String view_datee = view_date.getText().toString();

               String[] separated = view_datee.split(":");
               String first =separated[0];
               String second=separated[1]; 


               String[] newSeperated = first.split(" ");
               String third = newSeperated[0]; 
               String four=   newSeperated[1];



               Log.i("first",first);
               Log.i("second",second);

               Log.i("third", third);
               Log.i("four", four);
```

I do not how to get the four value means 08 .

Comment: Instead of splitting, you should parse the date and work on the date object. I will save you headaches and bugs.

Comment: i am getting the date form the time picker so it is giving me the whole string

Comment: Then you should definitely parse the date and work on a date object :) Check [this out](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html)

Comment: Try this SO solution
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3732790/android-split-string

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is an example using a date / calendar (it uses desktop java but easily transposable):

```
public static void main(String args[]) throws Exception {
    String data = "2013-1-31 08:25 PM";
    DateFormat fmt = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd hh:mm a");
    Calendar cal = Calendar.getInstance();
    cal.setTime(fmt.parse(data));
    //2013-1-31
    System.out.println(new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-M-dd").format(cal.getTime()));
    //20
    System.out.println(cal.get(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY));
    //08
    System.out.println(new SimpleDateFormat("hh").format(cal.getTime()));
}
```

Note that `08:25 PM` is `20:05` so you can get either 08 or 20 depending on what you need. I showed both in my example.

Answer (score 1):

Try this,

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
        String str = "2013-1-31 08:25 PM";
        System.out.println("[Date:"+str.split(" ")[0]+"][Hours:"+str.split(":")[0].split(" ")[1]+"]");
    }
```

Output,

```
run:
[Date:2013-1-31][Hours:08]
BUILD SUCCESSFUL (total time: 1 second)
```

Answer (score 0):

From the official [Javadoc](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#split(java.lang.String)), `split` takes a RegExp as argument.

So, you cannot use `" "` as `split` argument.

Instead, you should use `"\s"` to sepparate the string by whitespace.

Then, your code would be:

```
           String[] separated = view_datee.split(":");
           String first =separated[0];
           String second=separated[1]; 


           String[] newSeperated = first.split("\\s");
           String third = newSeperated[0]; 
           String four=   newSeperated[1];



           Log.i("first",first);
           Log.i("second",second);

           Log.i("third", third);
           Log.i("four", four);
```

Answer (score 0):

Are u sure String ends with PM Or AM
Then u can do like this

```
String s= "2013-1-31 08:25 PM";

        String newStr=s.substring(s.indexOf(" ")+1,s.lastIndexOf(" "));
        System.out.println(newStr);
        String result[]=newStr.split(":");
        System.out.println(result[0]);
        System.out.println(result[1]);
```

Answer (score 0):

check below code, its working properly

```
String date = "2013-1-31 08:25 PM";
    String[] split = date.split(":");
    System.out.println(split[0]+"date:::"  + split[1] );
    String[] Datesplit = split[0].split(" ");
    System.out.println(Datesplit[0]+"date splited:::"  + Datesplit[1] );
```

Output below

```
2013-1-31 08date:::25 PM
2013-1-31date splited:::08
```

Answer (score 0):

I have checked out your code and its working properly..
Here is i am posting whatever i have typed and excuted:

```
    String teststr = "2013-1-31 08:25 PM";
    System.out.println("teststr: " + teststr);
    String[] separated = teststr.split(":");
    String first = separated[0];
    String second = separated[1];
    String[] newSeperated = first.split(" ");
    String third = newSeperated[0];
    String four = newSeperated[1];
    System.out.println("first : "+first);
    System.out.println("second : "+second);
    System.out.println("third : "+third);
    System.out.println("fourth : "+four);
```

and its giving me following output:
teststr: 2013-1-31 08:25 PM
first : 2013-1-31 08
second : 25 PM
third : 2013-1-31
fourth : 08