# Android Split() function alternative

Tags: android

How we can split a given String at particular string or character as I do not wants to use Split function of android, is there any alternative available for that?

Comment: Please show some of your code so we can be of more help.

Comment: as I just used somestring.Split("a:b:c",":")[0] but I wants to write some code that it will work in a smooth way so wantsto look for an alternate code as I had an error that split function not defined so I am looking for alternate

Answer (score 2):

I would recon as an alternative the GUAVA Lib.

http://docs.guava-libraries.googlecode.com/git/javadoc/com/google/common/base/Splitter.html

Answer (score 1):

StringTokenizer is a good alternative, if you don't mind the iterative nature.

Here's a post related to that: [Android Split string](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3732790/android-split-string)

For example, from that post:

```
String myStr = "Fruit: they taste good"; 
StringTokenizer tokens = new StringTokenizer(myStr, ":");
String first = tokens.nextToken();// this will contain "Fruit"
String second = tokens.nextToken();// this will contain " they taste good"
```

Comment: it is somewhere a specific answer as it was assumed the string has always that syntax (foo: bar)..etc