# how to shorten spinner selected item text in android?

Tags: android, spinner

I have used android custom spinner.

My custom spinner look like bellow

[image]

My List data is like

```
 List<String> list = new ArrayList<String>();
    list.add("001-00434016457-Md. Mokhhlesur Rahman");
    list.add("001-00434016724-Mohammad Nazim Ullah");
    list.add("001-00434016725-Mohsin Kabir");
    list.add("001-00434016881-Maruf Pervaz Khan");
    list.add("001-00434017171-Md.Nazmul Hasan");
```

My Spinner Adapter and setting data in spinner is like bellow

```
Spinner spinner = (Spinner) findViewById(R.id.spinner);
ArrayAdapter<String> dataAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this,
            android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item, list);
 dataAdapter.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);
spinner.setAdapter(dataAdapter);
```

My problem is spinner's item text is large like "001-00434016881-Maruf Pervaz"

I want to select only id like 001-00434016881.

I don't want to get full text of the spinner item selection. How can I remove name part like -Maruf Pervaz Khan from 001-00434016881-Maruf Pervaz on item selection from spinner.

Please Help me

Comment: in spineer there is listner use this and also post code

Comment: what is the source for spinner data? posting code will be helpful.

Comment: check this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3732790/android-split-string

Comment: If you need only `001-00434016881` then you need to split your selected item string.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this. If the row item maintains same pattern as 001-00434016881-Md.Some Name

```
spinner.setOnItemSelectedListener(new OnItemSelectedListener() {

        @Override
        public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
            Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, adapter.getItem(position).substring(0,adapter.getItem(position).lastIndexOf("-")), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

        }

        @Override
        public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> parent) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        }
    });
```