# How to reset selected item of a spinner in android?

Tags: android, spinner

I get a part the text of spinner on selection using the code bellow

```
Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, adapter.getItem(position).substring(0,adapter
                .getItem(position).lastIndexOf("-")), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
```

When I select the spinner, I get text like

```
001-00434016881
```

Now I want to replace this text (001-00434016881) on

```
001-00434016881 - MAruf Parvez Khan
```

My spinner image like this....

[image]

I got some solution from [my previous question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29599063/how-to-shorten-spinner-selected-item-text-in-android) . But this my new problem.

Thanks in advance ...

Comment: And what do you display now with the current code. If you provide some more code (of your spinner, adapter, etc), it will be easier for us to help you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try this

```
String[] temp= yourSpinner.getSelectedItem().toString().split("-");

Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, temp[0]+"-"+temp[1], Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
```

Or if you want to show your toast when user select item from Spinner you can try this

```
@Override
public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> parent, View view,int pos, long arg3) 
{
    String[] temp= parent.getItemAtPosition(pos).toString().split("-");
    Toast.makeText(context, temp[0]+"-"+temp[1], Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
}
```