# TextView background with space between lines

Tags: android, textview

i would like to create a TextView with a colored background and space between each line, link this:
[image]

I'm trying with SpannableString but i can't create transparent space between lines, any idea?

Thanks and guys sorry for my BAD english.

Comment: Use  android:lineSpacingExtra

Answer (score 0):

Try using `lineSpacingExtra` and `lineSpacingMultiplier` in your XML file.

Comment: i've tried but with this attributes i can't achieve the transparent background

Answer (score 0):

If I am not taking wrong you want to add a transparent new line in your TextView ?

This can't be possible with single TextView as SpannableString will only effect the content of TextView and background of Textview is different from content of TextView.
If you have to achieve this then you have to provide custom implementation for TextView which will draw a transparent background in onDraw method for your custom view when in text content it find new line.

Or other option is to render a new textview for each line of text.

Answer (score 0):

Hi it should be done using add textview dynemically in layout and at that time you have to set properties of textview.You can do this like

> TvEx.java

```
public class TvEx extends Activity {
LinearLayout llMain;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.tv_ex);
    llMain = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.llmainTvEx);

    final int N = 10; // total number of textviews to add

    final TextView[] myTextViews = new TextView[N]; // create an empty
                                                    // array;

    for (int i = 0; i < N; i++) {
        // create a new textview
        final TextView rowTextView = new TextView(this);
        LinearLayout.LayoutParams buttonLayoutParams = new  LinearLayout.LayoutParams(LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
        buttonLayoutParams.setMargins(100, 20, 0, 0); // Set margins here
        // set some properties of rowTextView or something
        rowTextView.setText("This is row #" + i);
        rowTextView.setBackgroundColor(Color.WHITE);
        rowTextView.setLayoutParams(buttonLayoutParams);
        // add the textview to the linearlayout
        llMain.addView(rowTextView);
        // save a reference to the textview for later
        myTextViews[i] = rowTextView;
     }
   }
}
```

> tv_ex.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
   android:layout_width="match_parent"
   android:id="@+id/llmainTvEx"
   android:layout_height="match_parent"
   android:background="#A75653"
   android:orientation="vertical"></LinearLayout>
```

Comment: Using this code you can add Textview Dynemically and set properties to that and whenever there is newline you have consider it as new string and  can do what you want.

Comment: How to divide the text into rows?

Comment: using split the String : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3732790/android-split-string

Comment: But i need to split the string according to the width of the available space

Comment: it's dynamic, it comes from a web service

Comment: So what... If it is single string then for testing pass that string to understand that hows string that is and then i suggest you to how to split it in multiple string.