# How to Split a string by Comma And Received them Inside Different EditText in Android?

Tags: android, string, split

I have Two **EditText**(id=et_tnum,et_pass).  I Received a String like **12345,mari@123**  inside **EditText1(et_tnum)** . I want to Split them by Comma and After Comma i should Receive Remainder string into EditText2(et_pass). Here **12345,mari@123** is **Account Number** &  **Password** Respectively.

Comment: check my answer below

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
String CurrentString = "12345,mari@123";
String[] separated = CurrentString.split(",");
//If this Doesn't work please try as below
//String[] separated = CurrentString.split("\\,");
separated[0]; // this will contain "12345"
separated[1]; // this will contain "mari@123"
```

Also look at [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3732820/7320259):

> There are other ways to do it. For instance, you can use the StringTokenizer class (from java.util):
>
> ```
> StringTokenizer tokens = new StringTokenizer(CurrentString, ",");
> String first = tokens.nextToken();// this will contain "12345"
> String second = tokens.nextToken();// this will contain "mari@123"
> // in the case above I assumed the string has always that syntax (foo: bar)
> // but you may want to check if there are tokens or not using the hasMoreTokens method
> ```

Comment: Perfect answer Sir. if i want receive again,still that previous String is there. can i overwrite them?

Comment: Happy to help you :) :). Sorry I can't understand what you trying to say in comment

Comment: I upvoted your question. If possible do upvote to my answer

Comment: i mean, I've Successfully Received those Strings into Corresponding EditText. by second time if i receive Strings like that, new strings will be added with old strings, it cant be overwrites.. when i receive second time Old Strings should be Replaced by New Strings ..

Comment: In edittext if you do settext then it is automatically overwrite please check. you need to overwrite string?

Comment: ohhh i got sir, i used settext. it works well.. thanks again sir

Comment: welcome @M.m.Samy And I am not Sir. I am just a student :) :)

Comment: i have a doubt in php with mysql database. i cannot ask questions anymore, can u please help me ?

Answer (score 3):

```
String[] strSplit = YourString.split(",");
String str1 = strSplit[0];
String str2 = strSplit[1];

EditText1.setText(str1);
EditText2.setText(str2);
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use

```
String[] strArr = yourString.split("\\,");
et_tnum.setText(strArr[0]);
et_pass.setText(strArr[1]);
```

Answer (score 1):

Try

```
String[] data = str.split(",");

accountNumber = data[0];
password = data[1];
```