# Spliting a Text on multiple conditions

Tags: android

I am writing an app with Android Studio and I want to split a text into different values.
I have following text in result

```
*"Name: Peter;Age: 25; City: Chicago"*
```

I want to get:

```
*Name = Peter;
Age = 25;
City = Chicago;*
```

I used the search function and found these solutions: [Android Split string](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3732790/android-split-string#) but for my problem it seems to be too complicated.

Comment: can you elaborate what you mean as complicated??

Answer (score 1):

The easiest way is to use split() method.

```
String s1="Name: Peter;Age: 25; City: Chicago"; 
String[] words=s1.split(";");
//using java foreach loop to print elements of string array  
for(String w:words)
{  
Log.i("Words: ", w); 
}
```