# Formatting EditText and TextView with SpannableStringBuilder

Tags: android, android-edittext, textview, spannablestring

I have a TextView that displays texts retrieved from db and some parts of the texts are marked as comment.

Here is sample.....

```
// CREATE A VARIABLE AT THE CLASS LIKE THIS...
private static int delay = 4000; //4Secs

/*NOW THE DELAY METHOD*/
new Handler().postDelayed(new Runnable() {

    @Override
    public void run() {
        // DECLARE ACTIONS TO BE DELAYED HERE...
    }
}, delay);
```

Now i want all the single and multi line comment texts to have a different textColor. How do i go about this?

Answer (score 0):

If you format the String with html's font-color property then pass it to the method Html.fromHtml(your text here)

```
String text = "<font color=#cc0029>First Color</font> <font color=#ffcc00>Second Color</font>";
yourtextview.setText(Html.fromHtml(text));
```

or You can prints lines with multiple colors without HTML as:

```
SpannableStringBuilder builder = new SpannableStringBuilder();

SpannableString str1= new SpannableString("Text1");
str1.setSpan(new ForegroundColorSpan(Color.RED), 0, str1.length(), 0);
builder.append(str1);

SpannableString str2= new SpannableString("Text2");
str2.setSpan(new ForegroundColorSpan(Color.GREEN), 0, str2.length(), 0);
builder.append(str2);

TextView tv = (TextView) view.findViewById(android.R.id.text1);
tv.setText( builder, TextView.BufferType.SPANNABLE);
```

Comment: Please will this method automatically get those single and multi line comments and apply the color to it?

Comment: yes, try it to your code, and if got success, mark answer as correct.

Comment: please 'appMode' is underlined

Comment: please check answer is edited now. And if you got the result, then please mark answer as a Correct so that other can find this, and make it useful.

Comment: Pls i really appreciate your effort but all my text is retrieved from a single column 'SelectedItemsreader.getString(2)' not Text1 and Text2 so how do i seperate and format it?

Comment: You can split your like see [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3732790/android-split-string?answertab=votes#tab-top) and replace Text1 and Text2 with separated[0] and separated[1]. In example which is provided in link, you only need to just define your string like, String currentString = "Fruit: they taste good"; convert this to String currentString = SelectedItemsreader.getString(2);